# Toggle between boolean attributes JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, toggle

I have an event listener that I'm trying to toggle between a class (which is working) and a data-selection attribute of true/false (which is not). I have the data-selection attribute for div class="dice" already set to false by default.

```
game.selection = function() {
  $(".dice").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggle(function () {
      $(this).attr('data-selection', true);
    });
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  }); 
};
```

Comment: I fiddled with the code more and got it to KIND of work:

  $(".dice").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-selection', false)) {
      $(this).attr('data-selection', true);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  }); 

The issue with this now is it changes the data-selection to true when clicked, but does not toggle back to false when clicked a second time.

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-selection', $(this).attr('data-selection')=="false");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace :

```
$(this).toggle(function () {
  $(this).attr('data-selection', true);
});
```

by :

```
$(this).attr('data-selection', ($(this).attr('data-selection') == "false" ? true : false));
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-selection', ($(this).attr('data-selection') == "false" ? true : false));` is same as `$(this).attr('data-selection', $(this).attr('data-selection')=="false");` which is commented above :)

Comment: I agree, I saw you comment after posting my answer. (It was not there when I started writing it)

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function instead of [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). Also you can reduce the code to this.

```
$(this).data('selection', ! $(this).data('selection'));
```

Comment: if he set the data using `.attr()` will using `.data()` work?

Comment: @guradio no. it will not.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in two parameters to [`.attr(attributeName,value)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2), the second param sets the value.  You could write a custom extension, similar to [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to conditionally add or [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) like this:

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleAttr = function(attributeName, state) {
        return this.each(function() {
           if (state) {
             $(this).attr(attributeName,"")
           } else {
             $(this).removeAttr(attributeName)
           }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Then use like this:

```js
$(".class").toggleAttr("boolAt", false);
```